# How to write birth date regex for ISO8601 format with or without hyphens?

Tags: c#, regex

I want a regex to validate a birth date in ISO 8601 format like so: 1987-10-20 and without hyphens 19871020.

The regex I got work with hyphens:

```
> @"^(19|20)[0-9]{2}[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$";
```

This one accepts spaces or hyphens

```
@"^(19|20)[0-9]{2}( *|-)(0[1-9]|1[012])( *|-)(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$";
```

How to write the *nothing* instead of the space?

Thanks

David

Comment: Your regex works. Test it and see if there is some issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the quantifier `*` for the spaces: `( *|-)`. The meaning of `*` is: *Between **zero** and **unlimited** times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed*

Which means that, as of now `19871020` will be accepted as `1987  10 20` or even `1987                                1020`

I would recommend using a back reference and a capturing group:

```
@"^(19|20)[0-9]{2}([ -]?)(0[1-9]|1[012])\2(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$";
```

`([ -]?)` will allow 0 or 1 space or `-` and `\2` will refer to the first separator used. So `1987-10-20` will be accepted while `198710-20` will not. This is very useful for maintenance purpose, if you want to allow another separator in a near future, you'll have to update only one place and the job will be done.